# How do I transform a Ruby block and apply it as an argument to another block?

Tags: ruby

I'm reducing the verbosity on a lot of related specs with a small shortcut method I wrote:

```
def association_spec_for(kind, field)
  it { expect(subject).to send(kind, field) }
end
```

This gets used like this:

```
describe Student do
  association_spec_for :have_many, :courses
  association_spec_for :have_one, :transcript
end
```

Now I'd like to expand the way `association_spec_for` works, so that I can do this while still leaving the original use cases intact:

```
association_spec_for(:foo, :bar) do |a|
  a.baz(:blerp).bloop(:bleep => :blarg)
end
```

and have it turn into this:

```
it { expect(subject).to send(:foo, :bar).baz(:blerp).bloop(:bleep => :blarg) }

                                      # |----------------------------------|
                                      #    This part came from the block
                                      #      that was passed to a_s_f.
```

What's the best way to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def association_spec_for(kind, field, &pr)
  it{expect(subject).to pr ? pr.call(send(kind, field)) : send(kind, field)}
end
```

Comment: Won't that fail if no block is passed? (The block is optional.) I guess I can just have a conditional.

Comment: I'll update the question, but that's what I meant by "I'd like to expand the way it works...". The previous use cases shouldn't break.